# Triangular decomposition, and contained copies of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, roots

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra. Let $\Delta$ be the set of simple roots of $\mathfrak{g}$. Each simple root $\alpha$ gives way to two root spaces $\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha}$ and $\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$. Then I can take $[\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha},\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}]=\mathfrak{h}_\alpha$, and with some elbow grease show that these are all one dimensional.

Considering only the simple roots doesn't give all of the weight spaces. To obtain all of the weight spaces, I must consider all positive roots in $\Phi^+$.

I.e. our triangular decomposition is $$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\oplus\bigoplus_{\alpha\in \Phi^+} \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha}\oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha\in \Phi^+} \mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}$$

> 1) Am I correct, that I have: $$\mathfrak{g}=\bigoplus_{\alpha\in \Delta} \mathfrak{h}_\alpha \bigoplus_{\alpha\in \Phi^+}\mathfrak{g}_{\alpha}\bigoplus_{\alpha\in \Phi^+}\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha},$$ (note only the first direct sum considers just the simple roots.

---

> 2) How do I decompose this instead, to clearly see my $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ copies inside. It seems writing it like this, I can't see the $\mathfrak{h}_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \Phi^+\backslash\Delta$.

What I mean in point $2$ is, writing out decomposition, we either have redundancy when writing our $\mathfrak{h}_{\alpha}$'s by including all positive roots, or we lose out on seeing our embedded $\mathfrak{sl}_2$'s explicitly.

Comment: The Chevalley generators correspond to simple roots. Anyway, I hope you understand that there can be linear dependence among the $h_\alpha$, $\alpha\in\Delta^+$.